# Getting an error on making Https request using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying out a NodeJS sample file from a tutorial as I am new to NodeJS but I just can't make it work. I get an error when I run below code:

```
var https = require("https");
var fs =    require("fs");

var options = {
    hostname: "en.wikipedia.org",
    port: 443,
    path: "/wiki/George_Washington",
    method: "GET",
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res){ });

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(`here comes the error ${e}`);
});
```

I get the following error:

```
 here comes the error:
 Error:101057795:error:140770FC:SSLroutines:SSL23_GET_SERVunknownprotocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
```

I am clueless, I appreciate your help and insight :)

Update: Code had to be modified to go through a proxy server. I posted the solution and findings.

Comment: Try to `curl` the request, and see what headers are being sent

Comment: One thing you're missing is `req.end()` since you're using `https.request()` instead of `https.get()`.

Comment: Also, what version of node are you using?

Comment: Hi @mscdex, I tried adding req.end() to my code and it did not resolve the issue. It must be our company policies that blocks the connection. I am using Node version 6.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Here is a summary of the problem and the solution that worked for me.

I ran this code in another network and it worked fine. So I realized the issue is that I am running the code behind our corporate web proxy and I need to modify my code to go through the proxy system instead of making a direct connection to target web server. I tried to install https-proxy-agent module but it failed to install. Again, because I am behind the proxy system. There is a npm config settings file named .npmrc file which can be found under C:/users/[YOUR_USER]. I added below configs to .npmrc to be able to install new packages as was advised [Here](https://fak3r.com/2015/07/31/howto-use-npm-behind-a-corporate-proxy/).

```
proxy = http://172.26.128.35:3128/
https_proxy = http://172.26.128.35:3128/
strict-ssl = false
ca = null
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Finally I modified my code as below to make it go through and the proxy system and voila~, It worked like a charm. If you encountered this issue, I hope this helps.

```
var https = require("https");
var fs =    require("fs");
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxy = 'http://172.26.128.35:3128';
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);

var options = {
    hostname: "en.wikipedia.org",
    port: 443,
    path: "/wiki/George_Washington",
    method: "GET",
    agent: agent
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(`here comes the error ${e}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?

```
var https = require("https");
var fs =    require("fs");

var options = {
    hostname: "en.wikipedia.org",
    port: 443,
    path: "/wiki/George_Washington",
    method: "GET",
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(`here comes the error ${e}`);
});
```

Works fine for me!

Comment: Maybe it could be a problem with your connect. Have you tried to do a webservice call using the **curl** method? Try to do a telnet in this website with 443 port.

Comment: I just tried you code and It does not work for me though, I get the same mentioned error. It is very strange.

Comment: try to do this in your prompt or shell: **telnet en.wikipedia.org 443** and verify if you can stabilish connection

Comment: It took ages for me to enable telnet on my system and restart it, sorry for late reply. I tried **telnet en.wikipedia.org 443** and it says "Access denied  by security policy". I later try this code at home. I am just wondering, How is it that I can use a browser and go to wikipedi page over HTTPS protocol, but I cannot access it using Telnet or NodeJS ? What is the difference ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Telnet is a protocol used to stabilish connection with host in specified port. Using this tool you can verify if you have access for that.

Comment: As I see, you don't have access to do this operation. Maybe it can be your internet connection. Could be a proxy on yur browser. You should verify your connections.

Comment: Many Thanks Celso, you have helped me a lot. I just still not getting it, don't browsers need to establish connection with hosts in specified ports and protocols to be able to fetch contents ?  How do browsers behave differently from telnet and above NodeJS code ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Maybe could be a proxy configured in web browser or could be your network. Have you tried to run this code in another network or system? I hope it helps!

Comment: Celso I shared the solution, Thanks for helping out mate. cheers

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback